# Prove that the equality holds

Tags: probability, random-variable, covariance, conditional-expectation, conditional

How to prove that for any random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with finite variances, we have $Cov(X,Y)=E(Cov(X,Y|Z))+Cov(E(X|Z),E(Y|Z))$?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the analogous formula for variances, you can apply it to the identity

$$4\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y]=\mathrm{var}[X+Y]-\mathrm{var}[X-Y]$$